# How do you write a while loop using count on Python?

Tags: python

> If a list of numbers can be defined as follows:
>
> ```
> x=[22,25,45,32,21]
> ```
>
> Then, using the while loop count the number of items in the list. Print the final count.

I am having trouble. I'm trying to write it using count and len() function. Is there another way besides len() function. Thanks.

Comment: We don't answer homework questions here; we help you answer it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: what have you attempted so far? would be happy to help with that but no one here will do your assignment outright for you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you tell us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want to use `len()` or not? If you are already allowed to use it, this is trivial. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Is there another way of using while loop without using len() function? I need help and I am struggling with this question. give me tips or hints on it.

Comment: here is a hint, start with index 0 and iterate over the list until `list[i]` throws an error, then you know you reached the end of the list without using `len`

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.

Comment: @Prune, for homework, I can use all resources, but when I'm taking an exam I don't use SO. My class doesn't use ant sort of technology for exams. I try to find tutors, but they're busy. SO is a great tool for seeking advice and pro tips so I can improve my skills. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `len`, consider that:

1. You can use things like `x.pop()` or `del x[0]` to remove an item from the list.
2. `tuple(x) == tuple()` (or equivalently, `tuple(x) == tuple([])`) is `True` for a list `x` when and only when `x` is empty.

And, if you need to keep the original list intact, you can use `xcopy = x[:]` to make a shallow copy of `x` and use the above method on `xcopy`.

Answer (score -3):

This is homework but here is a solution:

```
x=[22,25,45,32,21]

counter = 0
while counter < len(x):
    counter += 1

print(counter)
#5
```

Without while:

```
counter = 0
for i in x:
    counter +=1
```

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. Also why would you loop up to len(x) *just to calculate len(x)*?!

Comment: Thank you Makis. How about not using len(x). Is there another way to write it?

Comment: The OP said that `len` and `while` should be used. So this is the only way to count the len. Of course just `len` would work but here we need the `while`